# A Star Implementation in Java

Tags: java, a-star

So I'm currently having trouble with the finishing touches of my A* Pathfinding, I have all of my necessary helper functions to do so, and I've actually implemented this algorithm in both Javascript and ActionScript, however I am tripping over using Lists in Java.

It comes up with no errors, but I need to get the finishing touches in so I can test to make sure it is functioning properly.

What I need to do is sort the openList so I can retrieve the lowest cost Node, this is where I need the help.

Here is what I have:

```
public class Pathfinding
{
    List<Node> closedList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    List<Node> openList = new ArrayList<Node>();

public Node calculateShortestDistance(List<Integer> tiles, Node start, Node goal, List<Integer> passableTiles)
{

    Node currentNode = new Node(start.row, start.col, start.gCost, start.fCost, null);

    while(!catchMeIfYouCan(currentNode, goal))
    {
        int row = currentNode.row;
        int col = currentNode.col + 1;

        addChild(row, col, tiles, passableTiles, currentNode, goal, openList, closedList);

        //left child
        col -= 2;
        addChild(row, col, tiles, passableTiles, currentNode, goal, openList, closedList);

        //top child
        col++;
        row--;
        addChild(row, col, tiles, passableTiles, currentNode, goal, openList, closedList);

        //bottom child
        row += 2;
        addChild(row, col, tiles, passableTiles, currentNode, goal, openList, closedList);

        //bottom right
        col++;
        addChild(row, col, tiles, passableTiles, currentNode, goal, openList, closedList);

        //bottom left
        col -= 2;
        addChild(row, col, tiles, passableTiles, currentNode, goal, openList, closedList);

        //top left
        row -= 2;
        addChild(row, col, tiles, passableTiles, currentNode, goal, openList, closedList);

        //top right
        col += 2;
        addChild(row, col, tiles, passableTiles, currentNode, goal, openList, closedList);

        //Put currentNode in the closedList
        closedList.add(currentNode);
        //Sort the openList

        //Assign currentNode to the last element in the List

    }
    return currentNode;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorting I think? I'm answering it...

Comment: You are correct Anubian, sorry if it that is not so clear. I edited it in hopes it makes it a bit clearer for onlookers.

Comment: Also, the code you provided is neither accurate or on topic...

Comment: How is the code not accurate nor on topic? I'm sorry you feel that way however this is the relevant section of code where I am having the issue.

Comment: Did you try anything before posting here? I know it's a bit of a moot question since you got the answer you're looking for, but being given answers isn't something that's always going to be possible... And my guess as to why the code isn't on topic is because none of your code shows your attempt at solving the problem. You just show code with `// Sort the openList` and (basically) ask "What do I put here to make this work?

Comment: I did try a few things, most answers pointed towards what Anubian had said but every attempt I made yielded errors. I'll be trying this here in just a moment and I'll report back my findings. The reason why that wasn't there, is due to my attempts earlier this morning to solve it, and in my frustration I removed what I had put. Coming back to it now I continued looking at it and searching around which yielded no good results (obviously) so I just posted what I had.

Comment: Just a tip, it's generally a good idea to post what you had tried, regardless of whether it worked -- we can always help you with what you have! (and showing good research effort means people may pay more attention) -- and you should really try to only put code that is *immediately* relevant to your efforts. I'd say a decent chunk of your code was just noise (all the `addChild()` stuff), which really doesn't help your immediate issue (how to sort `openList`). A short example that we could run ourselves would be even better if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting the list is pretty easy. First, you need to make Node Comparable:

```
class Node implements Comparable<Node>
```

Then you need to write:

```
public boolean compareTo(Node other)
```

That should be an equality test.

Then, you can easily use `Collections.sort()`:

```
Collections.sort(openList);
```